# Unable to retrieve debug logs from Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass

Tags: apex, authentication, debugging, auth-provider

I am now working on an implementation of an external authentication for SF. I am following [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/authproviderplugin.htm) and so far I was able to define and set up the [initiate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass_initiate) method and redirect to the correct URL. There I authorize and it sends me back to SF.

The question is: how can I debug the [handleCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass_handleCallback) and [getUserInfo()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass_getUserInfo) methods? I enabled debug logs for both my admin user(Auth. Provider "Execute as") and Site guest user, but in the logs I only see [initiate()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass_initiate), which then redirects me to the authenticator's site. I would assume that when it redirects me back, I would see the [handleCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm#apex_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass_handleCallback) debug log as Site guest user, but I do not.

Comment: does your context user change between then, can you log the user as well that you're logging in as and determine if that user is the one that is executing those codes after initiate?

Comment: how do you even check the context user change if the debug logs dont appear after initiate method?